# Вывод личных данных учетной записи пользователя

Tags: php, битрикс

Как можно вывести на страницу данные полей пользователя(залогининого), не используя компоненты?

Вывожу ФИО:

```
<?
global $USER;
echo $USER->GetFullNAme();
?>
```

Как мне тоже самое сделать , но для полей учетки? PERSONAL_NOTES  , WORK_NOTES  и прочие поля?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но ответ на Ваш вопрос есть в официальной [документации по АПИ](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuser/index.php)

Comment: @NikolajSarry Вы не поверите, но я настолько плох, что не смог разобраться и надежда была только на Вас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

global $USER;
$rsUser = CUser::GetByID($USER->GetID());
$arUser = $rsUser->Fetch();
print_r($arUser);

Получаете все поля пользователя без использования компонентов
В том числе и UF_ поля пользователя

Comment: а как выбрать не все поля, а именно PERSONAL_NOTES?

Comment: Ну на сколько я помню получить конкретные поля, например как при CIBlockElement::GetList() , возможности нет. Даже если юзать GetList пользователей, то всё равно вы получаете все поля каждого пользователя из списка.
По крайней мере, мы используем пример выше и не паримся

Answer (score 0):

```
global $USER;
$filter = Array("ID" => $USER->GetID());
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="desc"), $filter, array("FIELDS"=>array("PERSONAL_NOTES")));
while($ob = $rsUsers->Fetch()) {
    print_r($ob);
}
```

Comment: 1. Добавьте хоть одно предложение на русском, или источник откуда взято где есть разьяснения.  2. А если два поля?

Comment: в документации написано Массив с дополнительными параметрами метода. Может содержать ключи: 
SELECT - массив с идентификаторами пользовательских полей для их выборки в результат, например array("UF_TEXT_1", "UF_STRUCTURE").
NAV_PARAMS - массив с параметрами навигации, может использоваться для ограничения размера выборки. Например: array("nPageSize"=>"20"). 
FIELDS (с версии ядра 11.0.13) - массив с идентификаторами полей для выборки. Если не указан или пустой, то выбираются все поля. Возможные значения:

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос так, что бы не нужно было его уточнять. Там внизу есть кнопка править.